# SQL Server: INSERT from one table with explicit values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

UPDATE: Thank you to all who corrected my arg order and placement. I was able to correct my answer. It appears that that a previous question answered this (previously, I thought it was incompatible with SQL Server). I am open to feedback as to whether this should be taken down.

In SQL Server, is it possible to insert both information from another table AS WELL as explicit values? I am thinking something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GABAD01_CNTNR]
       (
       [ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAL02_ZONE_C]
       ,[ABAL03_ENVMT_C]
       ,[ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAD01_CNTNR_LOC_X]
       ,[ABAD01_CNTNR_K]
       ,[ABAD01_PARNT_CNTNR_K]
       ,[ABAD01_CRT_S]
       ,[ABAD01_CRT_CDSID_C]
       ,[ABAD01_LST_UPDT_S]
       ,[ABAD01_LST_UPDT_CDSID_C])
      ( SELECT
    (
       ([ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAL02_ZONE_C]
       ,[ABAL03_ENVMT_C]
       ,[ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAE01_CNTNR_LOC_X]
    ) FROM GABAE01_INFA_CNTNR WHERE ABAE01_INFA_CNTNR_K = 'DB_000000')
       ,'TBL_000000'
       ,'DB_000000'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'webd'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'webd')
GO
```

Comment: Of course it is, but that's not how you do it at all. You just select the constant value instead of a column name.

Comment: Yes, but your arg order is a bit wrong. You want `INSERT INTO target (a,b,c) SELECT col, 123, 'XYZ' FROM source;`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just put them in `SELECT` list:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GABAD01_CNTNR] (
       [ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAL02_ZONE_C]
       ,[ABAL03_ENVMT_C]
       ,[ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAD01_CNTNR_LOC_X]
       ,[ABAD01_CNTNR_K]
       ,[ABAD01_PARNT_CNTNR_K]
       ,[ABAD01_CRT_S]
       ,[ABAD01_CRT_CDSID_C]
       ,[ABAD01_LST_UPDT_S]
       ,[ABAD01_LST_UPDT_CDSID_C])
SELECT
        [ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAL02_ZONE_C]
       ,[ABAL03_ENVMT_C]
       ,[ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C]
       ,[ABAE01_CNTNR_LOC_X]
       ,'TBL_000000'
       ,'DB_000000'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'webd'
       ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       ,'webd'
FROM GABAE01_INFA_CNTNR 
WHERE ABAE01_INFA_CNTNR_K = 'DB_000000'
```

Comment: I see your copy & paste is faster then mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

Include the hard coded values in the select list:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GABAD01_CNTNR]
   (
   [ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C]
   ,[ABAL02_ZONE_C]
   ,[ABAL03_ENVMT_C]
   ,[ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C]
   ,[ABAD01_CNTNR_LOC_X]
   ,[ABAD01_CNTNR_K]
   ,[ABAD01_PARNT_CNTNR_K]
   ,[ABAD01_CRT_S]
   ,[ABAD01_CRT_CDSID_C]
   ,[ABAD01_LST_UPDT_S]
   ,[ABAD01_LST_UPDT_CDSID_C]
   )
   SELECT
   [ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C]
   ,[ABAL02_ZONE_C]
   ,[ABAL03_ENVMT_C]
   ,[ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C]
   ,[ABAE01_CNTNR_LOC_X]
   ,'TBL_000000'
   ,'DB_000000'
   ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ,'webd'
   ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   ,'webd'
 FROM GABAE01_INFA_CNTNR WHERE ABAE01_INFA_CNTNR_K = 'DB_000000'
```

Answer (score 2):

Include the explicit values in the `select`:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[GABAD01_CNTNR] ( . . . )
     SELECT [ABAL01_CNTNR_TYP_C], 
            [ABAL02_ZONE_C], 
            [ABAL03_ENVMT_C], 
            [ABAL06_LOC_TYP_C], 
            [ABAE01_CNTNR_LOC_X],
            'TBL_000000',
            'DB_000000',
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            'webd',
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            'webd'
    FROM GABAE01_INFA_CNTNR
    WHERE ABAE01_INFA_CNTNR_K = 'DB_000000';
```

Your extra parentheses don't help the query in any way.  I shorted the columns using `. . .`, so you can see `select` part more easily.